# jquery add and remove elements

Tags: jquery, click, element

I've been doing some work on a jQuery script of mine. What I currently have is an image and when clicked it will append an input type text.

$(document).ready(function() {

```
$('.addParticipant').click(function() {

    $('.addParticipantDiv').append('<p><img src="images/iconminus.jpg" style="width:38px; height:38px;cursor:pointer;position:absolute;margin-top:5px;-moz-border-radius: 4px;border-radius: 4px;" class="removeParticipant"/><input type="text" name="ck_email" class="mailitem" style="width:170px;background:#fff; margin-left:40px"/></p>');

});

$('.removeParticipant').click(function() {

    alert('oi');

});
```

});

However I've noticed that this do not work since I am trying to call a click event on a element that has been created dynamically with append. What would be the solution to this challenge? The alert or .removeParticipant does not work.

Comment: One possible solution would be to make a search before posting for over thousand duplicates relative to the exact same issue. You use correct terms for search, so no excuse... ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [jQuery .on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) (it was .live() before, but that's deprecated)

Comment: I tried this $(".removeParticipant").on("click",function(){
 
  alert("The paragraph was clicked.");
 
 }); However it did not do a thing. Am I missing something here?